# In python, how do you locate a specific word in a string file.

Tags: python

I know you can use seek() to find a specific byte and start reading from there. How do you find a specific word in a file and start reading from there. For example, how do I start reading a file from the word 'Origin'! Thanks for any help!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read a file to a string starting at a given word without knowing the line number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230362/how-can-i-read-a-file-to-a-string-starting-at-a-given-word-without-knowing-the-l)

Comment: I think the short answer here is you don't . seek (i think) involves a (possible) disk seek, therefor the byte number and a need to not know the values of the underlying bytes. Finding a word requires going through the file line by line and discarding the results until you find the right word

Comment: Thanks Mathew and negru. I just solved the problem by "going through the file line by line" with readline(). By using:                                                         while "Origin"not in l:                                             l = input_file.readline()  |||I have been able to read to where I wanted to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this efficiently by using the same algorithm that `grep` uses to find words. This is the [Boyer-Moore string search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore_string_search_algorithm).

Fundamentally you search for the *last letter* of the string. You do this by creating a list of all of the letters in your target word, and then you inspect letters in the file using seek. If you find a letter which is not in the word then you know that the word cannot end before the full length of the word, so you can skip that far ahead and test again. If the letter is in the word then you use the possible positions of it in the word to refine your search. If you find the last letter, then you can move back to the expected start of the word and check that it is as you expect.